# Looking for cells which contain certain value in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets where `Sheet 1` has three vendor number in `column A` and `Sheet 2` has a list of account names in `column B`.

I would like to search in `Sheet 1 column A` all cells where the value contains the cell value in `Sheet 2 column C`. For example, if the cells from `C2:C5` contain one of the value between `A2:A4`, `Sheet 2` cells from `E2:E5` will show `"Yes"` else showing nothing.

Below are my codes, but I keep getting an error message:

> "Invalid Next control variable reference".

```
Set sh1 = Worksheets("Vendor")
Set sh2 = Worksheets("Invoice")
Set r1 = sh1.Range("A2:A4")
Set sh1 = Worksheets("Vendor")
Set sh2 = Worksheets("Invoice")
Set r1 = sh1.Range("A2:A4")
Set r2 = sh2.Range("E2:E5")

For Each vendorCell In r2
    If cell = vendorCell Then
        cell = "Yes"
    Else
        cell = "out of range"
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to search in Sheet 1 column A all cells where the value contains the cell value in Sheet 2 column C. For example, if the cell from 'C2' to 'C5'contains one of the value between "A2" and "A4", sheet 2 cell from 'E2' to 'E5' will show "Yes" else showing nothing.

Your loop says `For Each vendorCell In r2` but then you are closing it with `Next cell` and hence you are getting that error. It should be `Next vendorCell`.

Having said that, I think this is what you are trying to achieve?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet: Set sh1 = Worksheets("Vendor")
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet: Set sh2 = Worksheets("Invoice")
    
    Dim r1 As Range: Set r1 = sh1.Range("A2:A4")
    Dim r2 As Range: Set r2 = sh2.Range("C2:C5")
    
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    
    '~~> Loop through col C
    For Each aCell In r2
        aCell.Offset(, 2).Value = "out of range"
        
        '~~> Loop through column A
        For Each bCell In r1
            If aCell.Value2 = bCell.Value2 Then
                '~~> Write to column E
                aCell.Offset(, 2).Value = "Yes"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next bCell
    Next aCell
End Sub
```

**Note**:

1. This is a very small range so using `For Next` is ok. Otherwise I would have recommended using `.Find`
2. BTW you do nto need VBA for this. You can achieve this using formulas as well :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it's not fully functional yet. When the code running, Range("E2:E5") only show "out of range"

Comment: I spotted a mistake. I have updated my post. You may have to refresh it to see it.

Comment: Thank you. Although the updated code can be running, i don't understand why Excel still throw message “Runtime Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set”?

Comment: bCell.Offset(, 2).Value = "out of range"

Comment: I finally created a sample so the above code is tried and tested now :). Try the updated code now. The loop was in reverse. I have fixed that as well.